# Next JS Taildwind CSS navbar issue with option dropDown

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, dropdown, navbar

I'm using this [navbar](https://flowbite.com/docs/components/navbar/#user-menu-dropdown)

I created one component with [navbar](https://flowbite.com/docs/components/navbar/#user-menu-dropdown), the I'm calling it on my `src/app/page.tsx`

```
"use client";
import Login from "../app/pages/login/page";
import Dashboard from "../app/pages/dashboard/page";
import { useAppSelector } from "./hooks/hooks";
import Header from "./components/layout/header";

export default function Home() {

  const userLogged = useAppSelector((state) => state.UserLogged.userLogged.onLine);

  return (
    <>
      { 
        userLogged?
          <>
            <Header />
            <Dashboard />
          </>
        :
          <Login /> 
      }       
    </>
  )
}
```

and I configure my `layout.tsx`, calling `flowbite.min.js`

```
  return (
      <html lang="en">
        <body>
            <Router>
              <Provider store={store}>
                {children}
              </Provider>
            </Router>   
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/1.6.6/flowbite.min.js"></script> 
        </body>
      </html>
  )
```

so I follow the [configuration](https://flowbite.com/docs/getting-started/quickstart/) of `flowbite`

so, the app run, perfect, but the option Dropdown on navBar is not working, what's wrong?? what I'm doing wrong?

notice that this error started coming up when i added the `<Provider store={store}>`

I was testing it, if I remove tags `Provider` and `Router` of my `layout.tsx` file, like:

```
  <html lang="en">
    <body>          
        {children}   
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/1.6.6/flowbite.min.js"></script> 
    </body>
  </html>
```

the option dropDown work:
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ii2T.png)

but if I add tags `Provider` and `Router` of my `layout.tsx` file, like:

```
      <html lang="en">
        <body>          
            <Router>
              <Provider store={store}>
                {children}
              </Provider>
            </Router>   
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/1.6.6/flowbite.min.js"></script> 
        </body>
      </html>
```

don't work the option dropDown:
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Xa3m.png)

you can check on [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/jovial-fire-sfz4p5?file=%2Fapp%2Fpages%2Flogin%2Fpage.tsx%3A14%2C108)

whe you in, click on "click here" and then you can see that the header dropdown is not working

Comment: I fixed it.... but, I'm getting another error with taildwind... I'm  going to update de question

Comment: *What* specifically isn't working? What is the error? Please [edit] to provide clearer details what exactly the problem is.

Comment: I Updated it, and added some images to, my issue is on my navBar

Comment: Would it be possible for you to create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of the code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: ready a updated..... I simulate the login, you only can click on "click here" and you can see that de navBar, If you click on phto profile or menu, not work the dropdown

Comment: FWIW when I comment out `Provider` and `Router` in the `app/Page.tsx` file the `Header` buttons/UI still don't work for me. I'm not sure what the issue is, but I'm fairly certain Redux and React Router haven't much to do with this issue since neither the `Provider` or `BrowserRouter` are visual components.

Comment: I was checking again, in `app/page.tsx` I comment ```useAppSelector((state) => state.UserLogged.userLogged.onLine);```  and just declare the variable ```const logged = true;```  and the button with dropdown worked, apparently the issu is when I call ```const logged = useAppSelector((state) => state.UserLogged.userLogged.onLine);```...... this is so strange

Comment: Yes, I did exactly that same thing when removing Redux from the render cycle. The UI didn't work either way, with or without.